# Passing struct to GPU with OpenCL that contains an array of floats

Tags: c, arrays, opencl

I currently have some data that I would like to pass to my GPU and the multiply it by 2.

I have created a struct which can  be seen here:

```
struct GPUPatternData
{
    cl_int nInput,nOutput,patternCount, offest;
    cl_float* patterns;
};
```

This struct should contain an array of floats. The array of floats I will not know untill run time as it is specified by the user.

The host code:

```
typedef struct GPUPatternDataContatiner
{

    int nodeInput,nodeOutput,patternCount, offest;
    float* patterns;
} GPUPatternData; 
__kernel void patternDataAddition(__global GPUPatternData* gpd,__global GPUPatternData* output)
{
    int index = get_global_id(0);
    if(index < gpd->patternCount)
    {
        output.patterns[index] = gpd.patterns[index]*2;
    }
}
```

Here is the Host code:

```
GPUPattern::GPUPatternData gpd;    
gpd.nodeInput = ptSet->getInputCount();
gpd.nodeOutput = ptSet->getOutputCount();
gpd.offest = gpd.nodeInput+gpd.nodeOutput;
gpd.patternCount = ptSet->getCount();
gpd.patterns = new cl_float [gpd.patternCount*gpd.offest];

GPUPattern::GPUPatternData gridC;
gridC.nodeInput = ptSet->getInputCount();
gridC.nodeOutput = ptSet->getOutputCount();
gridC.offest = gpd.nodeInput+gpd.nodeOutput;
gridC.patternCount = ptSet->getCount();
gridC.patterns = new cl_float [gpd.patternCount*gpd.offest];
```

All the data is initialized then initialized with values and then passed to the GPU

```
int elements = gpd.patternCount;
size_t ofsdf = sizeof(gridC);
size_t dataSize = sizeof(GPUPattern::GPUPatternData)+ (sizeof(cl_float)*elements);

cl_mem bufferA = clCreateBuffer(gpu.context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,dataSize,NULL,&err);
openCLErrorCheck(&err);
//Copy the buffer to the device
err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue,bufferA,CL_TRUE,0,dataSize,(void*)&gpd,0,NULL,NULL);

//This buffer is being written to only
cl_mem bufferC = clCreateBuffer(gpu.context,CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,dataSize,NULL,&err);
openCLErrorCheck(&err);
err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue,bufferC,CL_TRUE,0,dataSize,(void*)&gridC,0,NULL,NULL);
```

Everything is built which I check just watching the error which stays at 0

```
cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(gpu.context,1, (const char**) &kernelSource,NULL,&err);

////Build program
err = clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

char build[2048];
clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, gpu.device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 2048, build, NULL);

////Create kernal
cl_kernel kernal = clCreateKernel(program, "patternDataAddition",&err);

////Set kernal arguments
err  = clSetKernelArg(kernal,  0, sizeof(cl_mem), &bufferA);
err |= clSetKernelArg(kernal,  1, sizeof(cl_mem), &bufferC);
```

It is then kicked off

```
size_t globalWorkSize = 1024;
size_t localWorkSize = 512;

err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernal, 1, NULL, &globalWorkSize, &localWorkSize, 0, NULL, NULL); 

clFinish(queue);
```

Its at this point it all goes wrong

```
err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, bufferC, CL_TRUE, 0, dataSize, &gridC, 0, NULL, NULL);
clFinish(queue);
```

The error in this case is -5 (CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES).

Also if I change the line:

```
err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, bufferC, CL_TRUE, 0, dataSize, &gridC, 0, NULL,
```

to:

```
err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, bufferC, CL_TRUE, 0, dataSize*1000, &gridC, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

I get the error -30 (CL_INVALID_VALUE).

So my question is why am i getting the errors I am when reading back the buffer. Also I am not sure if I am unable to use a pointer to my float array as could this be giving me the wrong `sizeof()` used for `datasize` which gives me the wrong buffer size.

Comment: That's a good analysis, but what exactly is your question?

Comment: The error the when reading back the buffer. I am not sure if I am unable to use a pointer to me float array or is it that my buffer size is wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot pass a struct that contains pointers into OpenCL

http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf (Section 6.9)

You can either correct as Eric Bainville pointed out or if you are not very restrict on memory you can do something like

```
struct GPUPatternData
{
    cl_int nInput,nOutput,patternCount, offest;
    cl_float patterns[MAX_SIZE];
};
```

---

EDIT: OK if memory is an issue. Since you only use the `patterns` and `patternCount` you can copy the patterns from the struct and pass them to the kernel separately.

```
struct GPUPatternData
    {
        cl_int nInput,nOutput,patternCount, offest;
        cl_float patterns*;
    };
```

copy `patterns` to GPU from `gpd` and allocate space for `patterns` in `gridC` on GPU.
then

You can pass the buffers separately

```
__kernel void patternDataAddition(int gpd_patternCount,
    __global const float * gpd_Patterns,
    __global float * gridC_Patterns) {

    int index = get_global_id(0);
    if(index < gpd_patternCount)
    {
        gridC_Patterns[index] = gpd_Patterns[index]*2;
    }
}
```

when you come back from the kernel copy the data back to `gridC.patterns` directly

---

One more :

You don't have to change your CPU struct. It stays the same. However this part

```
size_t dataSize = sizeof(GPUPattern::GPUPatternData)+ (sizeof(cl_float)*elements);

cl_mem bufferA = clCreateBuffer(gpu.context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,dataSize,NULL,&err);
openCLErrorCheck(&err);
//Copy the buffer to the device
err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue,bufferA,CL_TRUE,0,dataSize,(void*)&gpd,0,NULL,NULL);
```

should be changed to something like

```
size_t dataSize = (sizeof(cl_float)*elements);  // HERE
float* gpd_dataPointer = gpd.patterns;    // HERE

cl_mem bufferA = clCreateBuffer(gpu.context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,dataSize,NULL,&err);
openCLErrorCheck(&err);

// Now use the gpd_dataPointer
err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue,bufferA,CL_TRUE,0,dataSize,(void*)&(gpd_dataPointer),0,NULL,NULL);
```

Same thing goes for the `gridC`

And when you copy back, copy it to `gridC_dataPointer` AKA `gridC.dataPointer`

**And then continue using the struct as if nothing happened.**

Comment: Is their another alternative to this? As I don't want to waste loads of memory, however, I need the data to be persistent as at a later time (a few mins later) it will be accessed for calculations

Comment: I have changed the struct to now be

typedef struct GPUPatternDataContatiner
{
    int nodeInput,nodeOutput,patternCount, offest;
    float patterns[100];
} GPUPatternData;

Anywat I pass this in and I want the whole struct to be read back. Both the structs are the same on each side.
I currently get the error -30 (CL_INVALID_VALUE). Nothing else has changed. Basically I NEED that struct as it will save a lot of hassle down the line

Comment: I have edited it once more. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably with the pointer inside your struct.

In this case, I would suggest to pass nInput,nOutput,patternCount,offset as kernel args, and the patterns as a buffer of float:

```
__kernel void patternDataAddition(int nInput,int nOutput,
    int patternCount,int offset,
    __global const float * inPatterns,
    __global float * outPatterns)
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that I create a struct out of the data that I pass in.

This data will be continually used by many kernels and needs to be persistent

Comment: You kernel would just update outPatterns[index] as you currently do.

Comment: Yer the persistent nature of the data is the issue with that method. I am changing the data only to check that it is in properly and can be accessed by reading it out

Answer (score -1):

I know that it is not actual now, but i passed this problem in other way:
Your code for allocation memory for struct with data stay same, but struct should bu changed to

```
typedef struct GPUPatternDataContatiner
{
    int nodeInput, nodeOutput, patternCount, offest;
    float patterns[0];
} GPUPatternData;
```

Using this "feature" i have created vectors for OpenCL