# __local struct array opencl

Tags: arrays, struct, opencl

I'm having some issues with this line of code:

```
__local cl_var new_vars[10];
```

These all work:

```
__local cl_var test;
__local int test[10];
__local cl_var * test
```

for reference, `cl_var` is:

```
typedef struct cl_var{
   int var;
   struct cl_var* next;
} cl_var;
```

I get a seg fault when trying to compile. Im using the JOCL package, not sure if that makes a difference.

Any reason why I cant have an array of structs declared locally?

(I have tried changing the struct definition to include local in various places)

Comment: I don't think you can include a pointer to itself. Since it is not yet defined. Additionally, it is generating an infinite recursion problem.

Comment: @DarkZeros I did have that problem initially, but including the struct keyword fixed that, I guess its a different namespace. Also, it is fine with it everywhere, except when using it as a local array.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae That is correct - weird right?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is memory alignment. According to this [article](http://enja.org/2011/03/30/adventures-in-opencl-part-3-constant-memory-structs/) and comments therein, you must be careful with alignment. The explanation of David Garcia in the commentary section of this page is pretty clear about alignment: some compilers may choose to pad struct size on 16 bytes.

There is important additional information in this [post in Khronos forum](https://www.khronos.org/message_boards/showthread.php/6863-OpenCL-struct-alignment-on-host-and-device):

> Basic data types in OpenCL (integer and float data types) have defined sizes and alignment requirements (refer to section 6.1.5 of the OpenCL 1.1 specification). To make sure the alignment matches between the host & OpenCL kernel that is using these data types on the device, use the cl_ for declaring structs that will be shared by the host and device (refer to table after table 6.1 in the 1.1 spec).

So you should use `cl_float` instead of `float`, and maybe also specify explicitly the alignment, if I understand the [spec page on basic OpenCL types](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/dataTypes.html):

> For 3-component vector data types, the size of the data type is 4 * sizeof(component). This means that a 3-component vector data type will be aligned to a 4 * sizeof(component) boundary.

So maybe explicit alignment will solve your problem.

Besides that, the second part of this answer:

> Note that this only works for integer & floating-point data types. The alignment rules do not work for pointers. This is one reason why pointers cannot be embedded inside a struct in OpenCL.

The OpenCL spec is very clear on this subject: "you cannot pass a struct that contains pointers into OpenCL" (quoted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639197/passing-struct-to-gpu-with-opencl-that-contains-an-array-of-floats), and confirmed also [there](https://www.khronos.org/message_boards/showthread.php/5936-Passing-pointers-in-a-struct), I'm too lazy to grab the spec page ... :) ). Obviously this is not the case here, but your struct won't be a valid type for a kernel argument.

Comment: I dont pass this to a kernel argument, these are all declared within the function, also - the only time it causes an issue is when used within a local array, when used in any of the other ways described it works.

Comment: Yeah that's why the pointer in struct thing is not really relevant, but I thought good to mention. But have you tried to declare a 16 byte alignment of the struct?

Comment: I havent, I'll look into doing that now, but why would that only affect a local array, not any other type of array, or a local pointer, or a local normal?

Comment: If my hypothesis is right, the problem is that it is a static array, with a size mismatch if the compiler assumes a 4-byte alignment. A pointer does not have this problem because you don't specify the size. Idem for a single variable. But it's an idea...

Comment: Interesting, I'll take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce the error at compilation time (or even runtime for that matter). I'm unfamiliar with JOCL so can't help in that direction.
I am using Windows, NVIDIA and JIT compilation for OpenCL kernels.

Do you also use the allocated memory in your kernel by accessing `new_vars` or do you only declare `__local cl_var new_vars[10];` and the error occurs?

Also what do you mean with "I have tried changing the struct definition to include local in various places"? Have you added the `local` address space qualifier to the "next" pointer?
If so then my following explanation may not be the solution.

From what I see, the potential cause for the error is a missing address space qualifier (can't verify since I am unable to reproduce the error). Your problem is that pointer types in OpenCL always come with an address space qualifier, `private`, `local`, `global` or `constant` (see [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/qualifiers.html)). If you leave it out, OpenCL chooses private by default: "Variables declared as pointers are considered to point to the __private address space if an address space qualifier is not specified" (see [Notes](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/private.html)).

This is what's happening to your struct. Within the struct you declare a pointer to the struct itself, however you do not specify any address space qualifiers, so private is set by default.

Writing

```
typedef struct cl_var{
   int var;
   struct cl_var* next;
} cl_var;
```

is equivalent to writing

```
typedef struct cl_var{
   int var;
   private struct cl_var* next;
} cl_var;
```

When statically allocating 10 cl_var objects in local memory by writing `__local cl_var new_vars[10];`, the address space qualifier does not match, as the objects reside in local memory, but expect to point to an object ("next") in private memory. So when using the pointer within the object, your program should crash, but only in run-time, not compilation-time (unless your compiler is very sensitive - which actually would be a good thing in this case).

By writing

```
typedef struct cl_var{
   int var;
   local struct cl_var* next;
} cl_var;
```

you should be able to allocate the memory.

Sidenote: Try to refrain from naming your arrays with "new", it may confuse people due its affiliation with dynamic memory allocation (and dynamic memory allocation is not what's happening in your sample code!).