# Passing C structures to OpenCL kernel

Tags: c, opencl, opencl-c

I have next structure in my host program:

```
typedef struct  s_figure
{
    cl_float        reflection;
    cl_int          color;
    enum e_figure   type;
    cl_float3       vector1;
    cl_float3       vector2;
    cl_float        param1;
    cl_float        param2;
}                       t_figure;
```

I have next structure in my kernel:

```
typedef struct          s_figure
{
    float       reflection;
    int         color;
    enum e_figure   type;
    float3      vector1;
    float3      vector2;
    float       param1;
    float       param2;
}                       t_figure;
```

Also you can see enum for both of it:

```
enum            e_figure
{
    BadFigure = -1,
    InfinitePlane = 0,
    Sphere = 1,
    InfiniteCylinder = 2,
    InfiniteCone = 3
};
```

While passing data to the OpenCL kernel in this way (where figures is an correct parsed structures array):

```
buf_figures = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, sizeof(t_figure) * figures_count, figures, &err);
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(view->cl->queue, buf_figures, CL_TRUE, 0,sizeof(t_figure) * figures_count, figures, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

I have a problems with data distortion, for example color after transferring data to OpenCL kernel can be changed to very different (0xFFFFFF->0x007FC2). Also raytrace algorithms works in another way every program execution. How can I fix it? I think gcc compiler make structures in different way than openclc but how to sync it?

Comment: cl_int is 32-bit, system int may be either 32 or 64. set color to int32_t

Comment: The second structure is opencl structure. Does it's int not compatible with cl_int?

Comment: _[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639197/passing-struct-to-gpu-with-opencl-that-contains-an-array-of-floats)_ may, or may not help.  Take a look.

Comment: As you can see my structure have no pointers

Comment: This may help, section 6/1 beginning on page 197 as well as section 6.1.5 Alignment of Types on page 203 in https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `__attribute__ ((packed))` for a struct declaration for both host and device. Otherwise different compilers (host compiler and device compiler) may create  different memory layout for a struct.

EDIT: Given that `sizeof(t_figure)` is 52 on both host and device, then the
root cause is probably not related to the struct.

Since you create a buffer with CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, there are some
caveats you need to consider:

1. `figures` pointer that you specify with `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR`
    must point to a valid memory while a buffer is alive, because it
    is actually used as an underlying memory storage for cl_mem object.
2. Buffer created with `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` already uses a memory
    (or a copy of it) pointed by `figures`, so a subsequent write
    with `clEnqueueWriteBuffer` is redundant here. More importantly,
    I'm not even sure how `clEnqueueWriteBuffer` behaves in this
    case, because this operation is essentially a `memcpy(figures,figures, size)`.

Comment: I have specified it for both struct declarations but after that program do the same.

Comment: Since all kernel execution no any function to change figure data, but it not like in host program.

Comment: @AndrewButok, can you check `sizeof(t_figure)` and dump its content using `printf` on host and device?

Comment: Both of them have 52 bytes

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect another possible root cause.

Comment: I find it helpful to put structures in largest-to-smallest order. It's not great for keeping things grouped nicely, but it reduces alignment issues greatly.